# Adding mod Values

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have the expression
$$\frac{1000}{2^k} - \frac{n \pmod{2^k} + (1000-n) \pmod{2^k}}{2^k}$$
I know that the value of the expression is an integer, and I suspect that it is
$$\frac{1000 - \ell \cdot (1000 \pmod{2^k})}{2^k}$$
for some integer $\ell$. Is my guess true? If it is true, then how do I prove it and find $\ell$? If not, then how can I simplify the original expression?

Note: I know that $(a \pmod{n} + b \pmod{n}) \pmod{n} = (a+b) \pmod{n}$ but here, I have the modulo surrounding the inside part, unlike the expression above. Can I still use this property, however?

Comment: Your guess is not true. Setting $k=n=1$ gives us that the former equals $499$ and the latter equals $500$.

Comment: I deleted my answer as it would take too much typing to adjust. Where I goofed was by using $[x - x]= [0]$ as if it were equal to 0. :)

Answer (score 1):

You write $b = a \mod m$ if b is the remainder in the division of $a$ by $m$, thus:

$$m|a-b$$
$$0\leq b < m$$

The first means also that there is an integer $q$ such that $a=mq+b$.

Let $U= n \mod 2^k$ and $V=(1000-n) \mod 2^k$

Thus there are integers $a,b$ such that

$$U=n-a2^k$$
$$V=1000-n-b2^k$$

Thus

$$\frac{n \mod 2^k + (1000-n)\mod 2^k}{2^k}=\frac{U+V}{2^k}=\frac{n-a2^k+1000-n-b2^k}{2^k}$$
$$=\frac{1000}{2^k}-(a+b)$$

Therefore

$$\frac{1000}{2^k}-\frac{n \mod 2^k + (1000-n)\mod 2^k}{2^k}=a+b$$

Where $a$ is the quotient of $n$ by $2^k$, and $b$ is the quotient of $1000-n$ by $2^k$.

---

Notice that this is true for any value of the integer $n$, even $n<0$ or $n>1000$, but remember the quotient of an arbitrary integer $K$ by a positive integer $M$ is $\mathrm{floor}(\frac{K}{M})$. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) for more about the floor function.

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't get me anywhere because I was trying to simplify $\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2^k}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{1000-n}{2^k}\right\rfloor$ itself. In your answer, $a$ and $b$ are precisely those numbers. I guess I should have asked the question like that to begin with...

Comment: @shardulc Yes, I guess :-)

Comment: Is there any other way to simplify this?

Comment: @shardulc Numerically, it seems that $floor(1000/2^k)-floor(n/2^k)-floor((1000-n)/2^k)$ is either $0$ or $1$, but I don't see the pattern. I'll have a look at this.